# Alternativa para Exists()

Tags: sql-server

Estou buscando uma alternativa para a utilização do comando `Exists` em procedures que eu preciso realizar uma consulta grande e verificar se a mesma retorna algum dado, caso ela não retorne a procure deve retornar um select com todas as suas colunas com o valor `'...'`.

Como estou fazendo no momento:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ..... FROM ..... WHERE .....) --Consulta muito grande, por isso não escrive ela.
BEGIN
    SELECT ..... FROM ..... WHERE .....
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT '...' as 'Col1', ....
END
```

O problema dessa abordagem é que eu preciso executar a consulta duas vezes, causando uma certa lentidão na procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não entendo exatamente como seu processo funciona, pois talvez exista uma forma melhor, mas algumas coisas que poderiam ajudar são:

1. Ao usar `EXISTS`, não precisa selecionar campo algum, você pode fazer `SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE ...` e economizar algumas leituras do disco. Por exemplo:

   > `SELECT 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ...`.
2. Não obrigue o banco a ler todos os registros, você pode usar o `TOP` para limitar o resultado, pois para `EXISTS` um registro basta. Por exemplo:

   > `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ... WHERE ...`

   O código acima vai retornar 1 se houver um registro, ou nada se não houver.
3. Se a ideia é apenas retornar algo, pode tentar retornar a query original e usar a variável `@@ROWCOUNT` para verificar se deu certo ou não. Exemplo:

```sql
-- tenta retornar
SELECT ..... FROM ..... WHERE .....

-- verifica se algo foi retornado
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
     -- retorna default
     SELECT '...' as 'Col1', ....
END
```

Nota: como foi mencionado pelo próprio AP em comentários, o `@@ROWCOUNT` só funciona se o parâmetro `NOCOUNT` estiver **desativado**. No caso de uma procedure, por exemplo, não pode houver o comando `SET NOCOUNT ON`.

Comment: Implementei a utilização do `@@ROWCOUNT` e alcancei o resultado esperado! Só gostaria de pedir que você adicionasse mais uma coisa na resposta antes que eu aceite a mesma: o @@ROWCOUNT funciona apenas se a stored procedure não tiver o comando `SET NOCOUNT ON;` no início da mesma, tive esse problema durante a implementação.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade Legal, boa observação, já editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é guardar o valor da consulta demorada e reutilizar depois. Você pode usar para isto `Table Variable` ou `Temp Table`. Desta forma, você faz a consulta uma única vez e reutiliza os dados retornados salvos na variável ou na tabela temporária.

Como você não especificou com detalhes sua consulta, fica mais difícil passar a resolução do problema com código, mas veja este exemplo pois te ajudará a escrever o SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7533172/2387977

É claro que terá um consumo maior de espaço em disco para este tipo de solução, mas pode valer a pena para seu problema de lentidão.

Comment: Essa é uma boa solução, mas quero que você entenda que optei pela resposta do @utluiz por conta de que a mesma é mais simples de ser implementada!